# optimize C function for time and space - check if a regex can represnt a given string

Tags: c, regex, optimization

I'm trying to optimize my solution to the following question:

> given a regular expression with chars and special char '*', (star which is a joker we can replace with any string), and a string, write a program which determines if the regular expression can represent that string or not.
> for example: "a'*b" can represent "aaaacbbbb" , in contrast "a'*b'*c" cant represent "aaaabcccccccccb"

I solved the problem and inserted the code below, I want to optimize either space or time, and if possible to make it more readable or shorter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int compareHelper(char *s, char *regex, int star);

int compareStrings(char *s, char *r);

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", compareStrings("aaaacbbb", "a*b"));
    printf("%d\n", compareStrings("aaaabccccccccb", "a*b*c"));
    return 0;

}

//aaaaacbbb
//a*b

int compareStrings(char *s, char *r)
{
    return compareHelper(s, r, 0);

}

int compareHelper(char *s, char *regex, int star)
{
    if (*s == '\0' && *regex == '\0')
    {
        return 1;
    } else if (*regex == '*')
    {
        return compareHelper(s, regex + 1, 1); // star is seen hence will be set to true.
    } else
    {
        if (!star)
        {
            if (*s != *regex)
            { // star was not seen and they differ in char
                return 0;
            } else
            {
                return compareHelper(s + 1, regex + 1, star);
            }

        } else
        {
            while (*s && *s != *regex)
            {
                s++;
            }
            if (*s == '\0') return 0;
            else
            {
                return compareHelper(s + 1, regex + 1, 0) | compareHelper(s + 1, regex, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question would be more appropriate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If this is a course assignment, you better to blame the teacher. The usage of the asterisk above is not a regular expression.

Comment: @tshiono Yes I know, Its a question from glassdoor actually.

Comment: You can certainly make it shorter...

Comment: @Shawn, may I ask for your help?

Comment: Oh, you have a bitwise or when you want a logical or.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a regular expression, it's a wildcard pattern, aka *glob*.

A pattern matching routine I had laying around to compare with yours:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

_Bool match(const char *glob, const char *s) {
  if (!*glob && !*s) {
    return 1;
  } else if (*glob == '\\') { // Escape character in the pattern
    if (!*(glob + 1)) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (*(glob + 1) == *s) {
      return match(glob + 2, s + 1);
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  } else if (*glob == '?') { // Match any one character
    return *s ? match(glob + 1, s + 1) : 0;
  } else if (*glob == '*') { // Match longest sequence of 0 or more characters
    const char *end = strchr(s, '\0');
    while (!match(glob + 1, end)) {
      end -= 1;
      if (end < s) {
        return 0;
      }
    }
    return 1;
  } else if (*glob == *s) { // Match exact character
    return match(glob + 1, s + 1);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

void compare_strings(const char *s, const char *glob) {
  printf("match(\"%s\", \"%s\") == %d\n", glob, s, match(glob, s));
}

int main(void) {
  compare_strings("aaaacbbb", "a*b");
  compare_strings("aaaabccccccccb", "a*b*c");
  compare_strings("accb", "a*c?b");
  compare_strings("accbbb", "a*c?b");
  compare_strings("ab*b", "a?\\*b");
  compare_strings("abbb", "a?\\*b");
  return 0;
}
```

It adds the ability to escape wildcards in the glob via backslash, and `?` to match a single character. It doesn't include character classes like you get with normal [shell globbing](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)
(though adding that is a good exercise). If you strip those parts out so it just includes `*` and literal character equality, it becomes very compact.

It also follows the convention that `*` matches the *longest* possible sequence, where it looks like yours tries to match the *shortest*. Just doing that simplifies things a lot - there's no need for an extra argument to tell if you're in the middle of a `*` match or not, for example, or special cases based on that state. Instead it jumps to the end of the search string, tries to match the rest of the pattern against that, and if it fails, backtracks and tries again against the last character of the search string, and so on until it succeeds, or fails to match after consuming 0 characters.

Comment: Something that would be fun to explore is optimizing for the case where you match many strings against the same pattern via compiling it to a state machine, bytecode or even JITted native code.

Comment: why are the compare_strings and match parameters are inverted?

Comment: Laziness, mostly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a suitable and very readable solution in GeeksforGeeks.

```
// The main function that checks if two given strings 
// match. The first string may contain wildcard characters 
bool match(char *first, char *second)
{
    // If we reach at the end of both strings, we are done
    if (*first == '\0' && *second == '\0')
        return true;

    // Make sure that the characters after '*' are present
    // in second string. This function assumes that the first
    // string will not contain two consecutive '*'
    if (*first == '*' && *(first + 1) != '\0' && *second == '\0')
        return false;

    // If the first string contains '?', or current characters
    // of both strings match
    if (*first == *second)
    {
        return match(first + 1, second + 1);
    }

    // If there is *, then there are two possibilities
    // a) We consider current character of second string
    // b) We ignore current character of second string.
    if (*first == '*')
        return match(first + 1, second) || match(first, second + 1);
    return false;
}
```